# The method GET is not allowed for this resource(python ,google app engine ,fb graph api)?

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7, webapp2

I am passing access token now i wants to get user imformation .when i am running this google app engine, it giving me error that:

The method GET is not allowed for this resource. Thanks in advance.
http://gprofile12321.appspot.com/loginfb
and one more error i have to send https:// to fb graph api

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = User()
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
        profile = graph.get_object("me")
        user = User(fb_user=str(profile["id"]),
                    name=profile["name"],
                    email=profile["email"],
                    access_token=cookie["access_token"])
        user.put()
```

Comment: what is your routing handler? Maybe that url is not served by the class you mentioned

Comment: application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', facebookhandler),
    ('/loginfb', BaseHandler),
    ('/profile', profilehandler),
    ('/update',update),
    ('/login',loginhandler),
    ('/delete',deletehandler),
    ('/merge',MergeHandler),
    ('/sign', Authhandler),
], debug=True)
t